# Is there any way to restrict inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Please provide a simple solution to restrict inheritance in C++.

Comment: Also, your question is far too broard. What does "restrict" mean? I guess you know inheritance in C++ already, so why did you not explain in what ways the standard modifiers are not sufficient for you?

Comment: Google `final` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u really dont want to inherit a class,then just make its member variables and member functions as private ,if other class tries to inherit it they cant have access to its funtions and variables anyways.
But using final is a better option

Comment: Yes, indeed, if you don't want to be able to derive from a class, write it so that it doesn't do anything useful. Not only will nobody be able to derive from it, nobody **want** to derive from it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! As of C++11, there's a [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) specifier you can use to indicate that a class cannot be inherited from:

```
class DontInheritMe final {
      // This class cannot be inherited from.
};
```

If you have experience in Java, the `final` keyword in C++ in this case works the same was as `final` classes in Java.

Comment: Be the way, it's worth mentioning that this specifier also may be placed on a virtual method to prevent overrides in a derived classes.